# prevent javascript calls from having delayed appearance

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have problem where a simple visual effect is not appearing when the call is made, but instead is being delayed substantially, pretty much until the point where it is moot.

I'm trying to get some data synchronously (yes, that's right, not asynchronously), put up a "waiting" indicator while it's happening, and then hide the indicator once the get is done. The problem is that the indicator is not appearing when the code doing it is executed; The visual result of a jQuery show() call isn't happening when the call is made - it is waiting until the data get is done. I have confirmed that the show() call really is happening before the data get by logging timestamps to the console.

Oddly though, the console logging is also getting delayed visually even though the timestamps confirm that the code is happening when you'd expect it to.

Last but far from least, if I introduce a call to alert() before the data get, then the visual stuff all happens when the alert goes up, it does not wait until the data get is done.

Here is the code. Note again that the data get is a *synchronous* call to $.ajax() (i.e. async: false).

```
fillInClient: function(clientId) {
  var result, spinner;
  console.log("spinning at " + ($.now()));
  spinner = $("tr#client_" + clientId + " .spinner");
  spinner.show();

  // if I call alert("foo") here, I see both of the spinner.show() and 
  // the first console.log immediately. Then after a few seconds, 
  // I see the hide, and the second console.log

  // Without alert(), I never see the show() and the first console.log
  // doesn't appear until after this:

  // this takes several seconds
  result = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/advisor/householding/accounts?user=" + clientId,
    async: false
  });  
  spinner.hide();
  console.log("stopping at " + ($.now()));
  return result;
}
```

Here is what I see in the console. Note that they appear effectively simultaneously, but you can see from the timestamps that they were called several seconds apart.

```
spinning at 1418933857688
stopping at 1418933862374
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `async: false` there's your problem

Comment: You need to put a 1ms delay between the show and the ajax

Comment: Synchronous I/O and JavaScript do not mesh well. Just use async code, it's not that much more work.

Comment: You never gave the browser time to render the show. you went from showing the spinner directly into a blocking piece of code. Note that the spinner will not *spin* while the blocking code is... blocking.

Comment: Why not run the ajax call as the `show()` callback function

Comment: And you don't really need to do this synchronously, just put your other code that you want to run (after the ajax call is complete) in the `success` or `complete` functions

Comment: Whoever voted my question down, would you please show some kindness? Ratings matter here - I had a legitimate misunderstanding that I was unable to resolve with numerous searches prior to posting. That means it's reasonable to think others might have a similar misunderstanding, and this question could help them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is going to attempt to do a repaint every `n` ms, and if the browser is blocked at that point in time (the call stack isn't empty), it will wait until the stack is empty to render. In your case, you're showing the spinner, sending a synchronous ajax request, and then hiding the spinner. This means that between showing the spinner and hiding the spinner, the callstack never empties, and therefore the browser never repaints, so your spinner is hidden before the browser gets to render it.

To resolve this, you need to move the blocking piece of code off the stack so that the browser render will happen before the browser is blocked. This is typically done using `setTimeout`, however, that will completely break the way your code works to the point where it might as well be an asynchronous request. Here's your code still using a synchronous request with `setTimeout`:

```
fillInClient: function(clientId, doneCallback) {
  var result, spinner;
  console.log("spinning at " + ($.now()));
  spinner = $("tr#client_" + clientId + " .spinner");
  spinner.show();

  setTimeout(function () {
    var result = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/advisor/householding/accounts?user=" + clientId,
      async: false
    });
    doneCallback && doneCallback(result);
    spinner.hide();
    console.log("stopping at " + ($.now()));
  }, 20);
  //return result;
}
```

As you can see, your function no longer returns the result and instead has to have a callback. At that point, you might as well just make it an asynchronous request and lose the `setTimeout`.

```
fillInClient: function(clientId, doneCallback) {
  var result, spinner;
  console.log("spinning at " + ($.now()));
  spinner = $("tr#client_" + clientId + " .spinner");
  spinner.show();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/advisor/householding/accounts?user=" + clientId
  })
  .done(doneCallback)
  .always(function () {
    spinner.hide();
    console.log("stopping at " + ($.now()));
  });
}
```

Comment: Other options include storing the result from inside the setTimeout to the outer result var that you returned, however, you still have to then have yet another setTimeout outside of all of this that will wait until `result` is populated. Very messy.

Comment: further reading: http://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html

Comment: Thanks, this was an excellent explanation of what was going on and why. One follow-up: How is it that spinner is defined and has the appropriate value inside the anonymous function being sent to always()?

Comment: It's called a Closure. It's a bit complicated to explain, i'd suggest searching for it in your favorite search engine. the TLDR version is: it's kept defined until the anonymous function is removed from the stack.

Comment: or, more precisely, until nothing references it.

Comment: Kevin, I didn't know that javascript could do closures like this, or at least I didn't know how; when I first tried, I'm not sure how my syntax was different, but the locals from the parent function were undefined in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I recommend.  Using AJAX for a synchronous request is completely unnecessary.  To provide a synchronous feel to your asynchronous code, use the callbacks.  Here's an example:

```
fillInClient: function(clientId) {
    var result, spinner;
    console.log("spinning at " + ($.now()));
    spinner = $("tr#client_" + clientId + " .spinner");
    spinner.show();
    result = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/advisor/householding/accounts?user=" + clientId,
        complete: function (){
            spinner.hide();
            console.log("stopping at " + ($.now()));

            //Other logic to run after the call completes
        }
    });
}
```

So, everything that you have after your synchronous function, I've moved to the `complete()` function so it will only run after the AJAX call is complete.  I can't think of any valid reason to do this another way.

Comment: The reason not to do it this way was that the return value was needed by the calling function. However I did not understand that it was the entire browser that was waiting for my code, not just my code. Now I understand why this really needs to be asynchronous. So I refactored to avoid the need for a return value at the caller.